# Case statement matching many regular expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Python *finally* got [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) in version 3.8.  But the discussion included:

> During the development of this PEP many people (supporters and critics
> both) have had a tendency to focus on toy examples on the one hand,
> and on overly complex examples on the other.
>
> The danger of toy examples is twofold: they are often too abstract to
> make anyone go "ooh, that's compelling", and they are easily refuted
> with "I would never write it that way anyway".

So here is a real example: I'm writing a DSL parser, I want it to run on Python versions other than the latest, and I can't figure out a *Pythonic* way to do it.

So if you would "never write it (the bottom code sample) that way", how **do** you write a case statement in Python 3.7 without using infinite nesting levels?

```py
import re

doc = """
 123 45 6789
   red sky at night
     abc42
       [foo, bar+, $)&%(@]
 ContentType: image/jpeg
"""

pat1 = r'^\s*(\w+)\s*$'
pat2 = r'^\s*(\d+(?:\s+\d+)*)\s*$'
pat3 = r'^\s*(\w+):\s*(\w+\/\w+)\s*$'
pat4 = r'^\s*\[([^]]+)\]\s*$'

# Python 3.8+
for line in doc.splitlines():
    if m := re.match(pat1, line):
        print(f'Type 1: |{m.group(1)}|')
    elif m := re.match(pat2, line):
        print(f'Type 2: |{m.group(1)}|')
    elif m := re.match(pat3, line):
        print(f'Type 3: |{m.group(1)}|{m.group(2)}|')
    elif m := re.match(pat4, line):
        print(f'Type 4: |{m.group(1)}|')
    elif line:
        print(f'Unknown Format: |{line}|')

print('=============')

# Python 3.x <3.8
for line in doc.splitlines():
    m = re.match(pat1, line)
    if m:
        print(f'Type 1: |{m.group(1)}|')
    else:
        m = re.match(pat2, line)
        if m:
            print(f'Type 2: |{m.group(1)}|')
        else:
            m = re.match(pat3, line)
            if m:
                print(f'Type 3: |{m.group(1)}|{m.group(2)}|')
            else:
                m = re.match(pat4, line)
                if m:
                    print(f'Type 4: |{m.group(1)}|')
                elif line:
                    print(f'Unknown Format: |{line}|')
```

The output doesn't matter, it's a toy example to illustrate a real problem. But for the record running under Python 3.7 generates a syntax error.

Running under Python 3.8 produces:

```
Type 2: |123 45 6789|
Unknown Format: |   red sky at night|
Type 1: |abc42|
Type 4: |foo, bar+, $)&%(@|
Type 3: |ContentType|image/jpeg|
=============
Type 2: |123 45 6789|
Unknown Format: |   red sky at night|
Type 1: |abc42|
Type 4: |foo, bar+, $)&%(@|
Type 3: |ContentType|image/jpeg|
```

---

**EDIT:**

khelwood's approach is the the most straightforward.  Easy to understand at a glance, more so than looping over patterns or dispatching.

It's still way uglier than the Python 3.8 version. I have no idea why anyone would be against assignment expressions or why Python took so long to get them.

```py
# Python 3.7
def process_line(ln):
    m = re.match(pat1, ln)
    if m:
        print(f'Type 1: |{m.group(1)}|')
        return
    m = re.match(pat2, ln)
    if m:
        print(f'Type 2: |{m.group(1)}|')
        return
    m = re.match(pat3, ln)
    if m:
        print(f'Type 3: |{m.group(1)}|{m.group(2)}|')
        return
    m = re.match(pat4, ln)
    if m:
        print(f'Type 4: |{m.group(1)}|')
        return
    print(f'Unknown Format: |{ln}|')

for line in doc.splitlines():
    if line:
        process_line(line)
```

---

**EDIT**(orial) #2:

Now I know why it took so long for Python to implement such a simple and useful idea: [PEP 572 Controversy](https://lwn.net/Articles/757713/).  Disgust with the whole fiasco caused Python's creator to step down permanently, and is a cautionary tale on the perils of design by committee. Shame on those responsible for this loss.
</editorial>

Comment: If you put it in a function you could return at each match and avoid the nesting of your if statements.

Comment: Loop over the possible expressions...

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, using a dictionary of patterns (dispatch table). I'm searching for the matching pattern, and then calling the function (lambda, in this case) associated with it.

```
import re
doc = """123 45 6789
   red sky at night
     abc42
       [foo, bar+, $)&%(@]
 ContentType: image/jpeg
"""

pat0 = r'^\s*(\w+)\s*$'
pat1 = r'^\s*(\d+(?:\s+\d+)*)\s*$'
pat2 = r'^\s*(\w+):\s*(\w+\/\w+)\s*$'
pat3 = r'^\s*\[([^]]+)\]\s*$'

d = OrderedDict([
    (pat0, lambda m: print(f'Type 1: |{m.group(1)}|')), 
    (pat1, lambda m: print(f'Type 2: |{m.group(1)}|')), 
    (pat2, lambda m: print(f'Type 3: |{m.group(1)}|{m.group(2)}|')), 
    (pat3, lambda m: print(f'Type 4: |{m.group(1)}|'))    
])

for line in doc.splitlines():
    # look for the first pattern that matches the line 
    pattern = next((pat for pat in d.keys() if re.match(pat, line)), None)
    if pattern:
        m = re.match(pattern, line)
        d[pattern](m)
    else: 
        print(f'Unknown Format: |{line}|')
```

Comment: Thanks - I always like table-driven solutions.  I don't thing lambdas will work when the processing of each case is larger than a print statement, but a dispatch table would be similar.

Comment: Indeed, I've used lambda because it's short, but it would be 'real' functions in a more realistic scenario.

Comment: I would try to play around with this to terminate when a match is found rather than evaluating all the regexes in a comprehension ... perhaps by generating an exception in the comprehension for the good case and dispatching in the except.

Comment: You can short circuit this. Also, you may explicitly want to use `OrderedDict` for older versions of python.

Comment: @Dave -  Incorporated your comments.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate a switch-statement, I use a one-line helper function:

```
def switch(v): yield lambda *c:v in c
```

It can be used with if/elif/else statements

```
x = 1
for case in switch(x):
    if   case(1):   doSomething()
    elif case(2,3): doSomethingElse()
    elif case(4):   doAnotherThing()
    else:           handleOtherCases()
```

Or in a more C-like switch structure:

```
x = 1
for case in switch(x):

    if case(1):
        # do something
        break

    if case(2,3):
        # do something else
        break
else:
    # handle other cases...
```

Using an improved version of this that accepts an optional matching function, you could make that Python 3.7 code more palatable:

```
def switch(v, match=None):
    if not match: yield lambda *c:v in c; return
    last = None
    def case(*c):
        nonlocal last
        if c: last = next((r for r in (match(p,v) for p in c) if r),None)
        return last
    yield case


# with a match function, case() without parameter returns the last match value
```

The Python 3.7 code could then be written like this:

```
for line in doc.splitlines():

    for case in switch(line, re.match):
        if   case(pat1): print(f'Type 1: |{case().group(1)}|')
        elif case(pat2): print(f'Type 2: |{case().group(1)}|')
        elif case(pat3): print(f'Type 3: |{case().group(1)}|{case().group(2)}|')
        elif case(pat4): print(f'Type 4: |{case().group(1)}|')
        elif line:       print(f'Unknown Format: |{line}|')
```

Or in a more C-like style (likely when more than a mere print call is made in each case):

```
for line in doc.splitlines():

    for case in switch(line, re.match):
        if case(pat1): 
            print(f'Type 1: |{case().group(1)}|')
            break

        if case(pat2): 
            print(f'Type 2: |{case().group(1)}|')
            break

        if case(pat3): 
            print(f'Type 3: |{case().group(1)}|{case().group(2)}|')
            break

        if case(pat4): 
            print(f'Type 4: |{case().group(1)}|')
            break

        if line:
           print(f'Unknown Format: |{line}|')
```

*note that the `break` statements here only go out of the `for case in switch...` they don't break the `for line in ...` outer loop.*

With Python 3.8, you could could make the switch function simpler and assign the match returns in the conditions if you need them:

```
def switch(v,match=None):
    if not match: 
        yield lambda *c: v in c
    else:
        yield lambda *c: next((r for r in (match(p,v) for p in c) if r),None)
```

...

```
for line in doc.splitlines():

    for case in switch(line, re.match):
        if   m := case(pat1): print(f'Type 1: |{m.group(1)}|')
        elif m := case(pat2): print(f'Type 2: |{m.group(1)}|')
        elif m := case(pat3): print(f'Type 3: |{m.group(1)}|{m.group(2)}|')
        elif m := case(pat4): print(f'Type 4: |{m.group(1)}|')
        elif line:            print(f'Unknown Format: |{line}|')
```

In both versions you can specify multiple patterns on case conditions (the first match is returned):

```
for line in doc.splitlines():

    for case in switch(line, re.match):
        if not line: break

        if case(pat1,pat2): 
            print(f'Type 1 or 2: |{case().group(1)}|')
            break

        if case(pat3): 
            print(f'Type 3: |{case().group(1)}|{case().group(2)}|')
            break

        if case(pat4): 
            print(f'Type 4: |{case().group(1)}|')
            break
    else:            
        print(f'Unknown Format: |{line}|')

# output:

Type 1 or 2: |123 45 6789|
Unknown Format: |   red sky at night|
Type 1 or 2: |abc42|
Type 4: |foo, bar+, $)&%(@|
Type 3: |ContentType|image/jpeg|
```